# LIKE query to find column values that are substrings of a longer string

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, sql-like

I want to use this code to find a value in field PID where it may exist anywhere in field MP_PID but my SQL is not catching them. No errors are thrown. What am I doing wrong?

It is comparing values from text fields in both recordsets.

Thanks

TMA

```
strPID = "DELETE * FROM tblPID WHERE PID Like '*" & !MP_PID & "*';"
```

If I use:

```
strPID = "DELETE * FROM tblPID WHERE PID = '" & !MP_PID & "';"
```

It works fine for exact matches.

Access 2007 DAO

What is wrong with my like statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

LIKE expressions are used to identify records where the value on the left side of the LIKE operator contains a string (or pattern of characters) represented by the wildcard string on the right side of the LIKE operator.

In your case

```sql
... '0123456A' LIKE '*0000623E 0123456A*'
```

will return False because the left side does not contain the entire string on the right side.

What you really want is

```sql
... '0000623E 0123456A' LIKE '*0123456A*'
```

which means that you need the MP_PID value on the left side of the LIKE operator.

To do that correctly (i.e., with a parameterized query) would look something like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub LikeTest()
    ' test data
    Dim MP_PID As String
    MP_PID = "0000623E 0123456A"

    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("", _
            "PARAMETERS [LongerText] TEXT(255);" & _
            "DELETE * FROM tblPID WHERE [LongerText] LIKE '*' & PID & '*'")
    qdf!LongerText = MP_PID
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
    Debug.Print qdf.RecordsAffected & " record(s) deleted."
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

PID is most likely a numeric field and you use the `LIKE` operator which traverses string values. Try converting numeric value to string:

```
strPID = "DELETE * FROM tblPID WHERE CSTR(PID) Like '*" & !MP_PID & "*';"
```

Alternatively, concatenate an empty length string value to numeric value (similar to converting textbox numeric value to string by concatenating asterisks and quotes):

```
strPID = "DELETE * FROM tblPID WHERE PID & '' Like '*" & !MP_PID & "*';"
```

Comment: Both are definitely strings. I tried both renditions and where the matches are exact the like statement works. So I am still at a loss. Where PID = 0123456A and !MP_PID = '0123456A' it works. If PID = '0123456A' and !MP_PID = '0000623E 0123456A' it does not work. There is a space between values in !MP_PID if that matters

Comment: @Darwind - If you want to search for a PID value *within* an MP_PID value then you need to reverse the order in which they appear in the LIKE expression.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Gord and Parfait. You both got me on the correct path and yes I did have it back asswards. Here is what I used to create a delete query:

```
        strDelMP = "DELETE tblPID.* FROM tblPID INNER JOIN tblMgtPlan ON tblMgtPlan.MP_PID Like '*' + tblPID.PID + '*';"
    db.Execute (strDelMP)
```

Thanks!